# How to force idle workers to take jobs in parallel R?

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am new to posting here--I searched and couldn't find an answer to my question.  I have run the following R parallelized code (from a [blog](http://librestats.com/2012/03/15/a-no-bs-guide-to-the-basics-of-parallelization-in-r/) on parallel computing in R) using the `parallel` package on two different machines and yet get very different process time results.   The first machine is a Lenovo laptop with Windows 8, 8GB RAM, Intel i7, 2 cores/4 logical processors.   The second machine is a Dell desktop, Windows 7, 16GB RAM, Intel i7, 4 cores/8 logical processors.  The code sometimes runs much slower on the second machine.  I believe the reason is that the second machine is not using the worker nodes to complete the task.  When I use the function snow.time() from the `snow` package to check node usage, the first machine is using all available workers to complete the task.  However, on the more powerful machine, it never uses the workers--the entire task is handled by the master.  Why is the first machine using workers, but the second is not with the exact same code?  And how do I 'force' the second machine to use the available workers so that the code is truly parallelized and the processing time is sped up?  The answers to these would help me tremendously with other work I am doing.  Thanks in advance.  The graphs from the function `snow.time()` are below as well as the code I used:
[image: Laptop CPU Usage]
[image: PC CPU Usage]

```
runs <- 1e7
manyruns <- function(n) mean(unlist(lapply(X=1:(runs/4), FUN=onerun)))

library(parallel)
cores <- 4
cl <- makeCluster(cores)

# Send function to workers
tobeignored <- clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    onerun <- function(.){ # Function of no arguments
        doors <- 1:3
        prize.door <- sample(doors, size=1)
        choice <- sample(doors, size=1)
        if (choice==prize.door) return(0) else return(1) # Always switch
    }
    ; NULL
})

# Send runs to the workers
tobeignored <- clusterEvalQ(cl, {runs <- 1e7; NULL})
runtime <- snow.time(avg <- mean(unlist(clusterApply(cl=cl, x=rep(runs, 4), fun=manyruns))))
stopCluster(cl)

plot(runtime)
```

Comment: Can you check your task manager and see what the workers are doing?  I amended the code a bit and seems like all of them are busy (on linux though.)

Comment: Task Manager shows 4 R sessions as expected, with CPU level at 13 for each.  But snow.time() continues to show that only the master was used for processing, with the desktime time taking way longer (229 sec) than the laptop (5.3 seconds using all 4 cores).  Should I look for something else in the task manager?

Comment: Only have cell phone right now. .. a) make explicit cluster type  (mpi, socket ). I have seen this behavior with fork cluster on Linux. b) simplify code, remove clusterEval, retain only makeCluster and parLapply. c) restart R.

Comment: @OttToomet, tried your suggestions, but they did not resolve--I still have same issue.  Also, the original code works beautifully in parallel on laptop, so it is still a mystery why it doesn't on desktop.  Maybe to Greg Snow's point, it has to do with version of R.  Will investigate this next.

Comment: Try using Revolution Analytics' R distribution first. 13% CPU is *very* bad, but typical of vanilla R which can't use SIMD CPU commands. RRO on the other hand uses Intel's Math libraries to exploit both SIMD commands (eg processing 4 floats per tick instead of 1) *and* multiple cores. On an i7 (quad core with HT) CPU i've seen 7x improvement when running `svd` on a large matrix. That's *better* than trying to run 4 processes in parallel.

Comment: It occurred to me that I should add the snow.time() output graphs that I referred to in the original post.  I updated the post to include.   Notice that with the PC, the graph shows that it never used workers to process.  Is this the correct interpretation?   BTW, for some reason today, the PC is nevertheless processing faster than laptop even though it is only using master to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use the `snow.timing` function from the snow package while getting all of the other functions from the parallel package. The source for parallel in R 3.2.3 has some place holder code for timing, but it doesn't appear to be either complete or compatible with the `snow.timing` function in snow. I think you'll still get correct results from `clusterApply`, but the object returned by `snow.time` will be equivalent to executing:

```
runtime <- snow.time(Sys.sleep(20))
```

If you want to use `snow.timing`, I suggest only loading snow, although you can still access functions such as `detectCores` using the syntax `parallel::detectCores()`.

I don't really know why your script occasionally runs slowly on your desktop machine, but I think that the way you are parallelizing it is reasonable and correct. You might want to try benchmarking `manyruns` sequentially on both machines in order to rule out any differences in the random number generation code on the two systems. But perhaps the problem was caused by a system service that was slowing down the whole system.

Comment: thank you for this answer.  This indeed turned out to be the issue.  When I loaded `snow` only and ran the code, I got the expected output from the graph on both computers showing that all workers were busy on the code.

Answer (score 5):

Try `clusterApplyLB` instead of `clusterApply`.  The "LB" is for load balancing.

The non LB version divides the number of tasks between the nodes and sends them in a batch, but if one node finishes early then it sits idle waiting for the others.

The LB version sends one task to each node then watches the nodes and when a node finishes it sends another task to that node until all the tasks are assigned.  This is more efficient if the time for each task varies widely, but is less efficient if all the tasks will take about the same amount of time.

Also check the versions of R and parallel.  If I am remembering correctly the `clusterApply` function used to not do things in parallel on Windows machines (but I don't see that note any more, so that has likely been remedied in recent versions), so the difference could be different versions of the parallel package.  The `parLapply` function did not have the same issue, so you could rewrite your code to use it instead and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried using cluserApplyLB as  well as parLapply and parLapplyLB.  I'm seeing the same issue, so it did not resolve this problem.

Comment: @KUZ, did you check your version of R and the parallel package?

Comment: yes:  the laptop has R 3.1.1 for a 64-bit machine.  The desktop has R 3.1.3 for a 6- bit machine.  On both machines, I am using the `parallel` package that come with R.

Comment: @KUZ, so the machine that is not using all the cores has the newer version of R.  That is counter to my theory of changes to the package being the explanation.  Only other thing I can think is that the OS is doing something different its interaction with R.

Comment: Since each cluster worker executes `manyruns` exactly once, clusterApply and clusterApplyLB are equivalent since the load balancing only comes into play after each worker has been scheduled one task.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot put code in comments...  I do no understand your program very well.  What kind of cluster are you creating?  Try this, adjust 2e6 to whatever works for you:

```
library(parallel)
library(Rmpi)
library(snow)
cl <- makeMPIcluster(3)
t <- system.time(parLapply(cl, 1:100, function(i) mean(rnorm(2e6))))
stopCluster(cl)
print(t)
```

for me it runs for 10 seconds (2 core/hyperthreading/5y old laptop/linux), all 4 workers are 100% busy.  You may also try the same with socket clusters.

Comment: for some reason, I'm unable to load 'Rmpi' on both of my computers, so I'm unable to try your solution.  I get the error message "Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rmpi', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/kukanwaz/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rmpi/libs/x64/Rmpi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rmpi’.  A separate issue I will need to address later...

Comment: Seems you don't have openMPI installed.  But what happens if you replace makeMPIcluster with makePSOCKcluster and remove libraries Rmpi and snow?